# Trying to send a comment to instagram via my JS app

Tags: javascript

trying to send a comment to instagram, using this code:

```
request({ url: proxyURL + url, method: req.method, json: reqData },
  (error) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }).pipe(res);
```

But i'm getting 
meta
:
{code: 400, error_type: "APIInvalidParametersError", error_message: "Missing 'text'"}

P.S. In JSON obg i have a field "text"

Comment: what's the value of `reqData`?

Comment: {"text":"test"}

Comment: also - what's the url?

Comment: @hackerrdave https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media-id}/comments?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text comment data needs to be sent as form data, per Instagram docs:

```
curl -F 'access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN' \
     -F 'text=This+is+my+comment' \
     https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media-id}/comments
```

That means with `request` you just need to use `form` instead of `json`:

```
request({ url: proxyURL + url, method: req.method, form: reqData },
  (error) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
}).pipe(res);
```

Comment: thanx, didn't know this.